# ¿Cómo se usa condición where mismo campo varios valores en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla en MySQL con el siguiente datos:

Nombre de la tabla error

| account_id | code | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18638 | 4635 | 13/07/2023 16:42 |
| 19610 | 1123 | 01/10/2023 11:53 |
| 19610 | 4657 | 02/10/2023 9:48 |
| 19610 | 4657 | 02/10/2023 19:02 |
| 19610 | 1538 | 02/10/2023 19:43 |
| 19610 | 4635 | 02/10/2023 20:01 |
| 19610 | 4657 | 03/10/2023 8:49 |
| 19610 | 4657 | 03/10/2023 10:41 |
| 19610 | 2457 | 03/10/2023 12:40 |
| 19610 | 4657 | 03/10/2023 14:26 |
| 19610 | 4657 | 03/10/2023 15:26 |
| 19610 | 4657 | 04/10/2023 8:36 |
| 19610 | 4657 | 04/10/2023 15:59 |
| 19610 | 5554 | 05/10/2023 9:46 |
| 19610 | 4657 | 05/10/2023 10:28 |
| 18499 | 4635 | 06/10/2023 0:28 |
| 19610 | 4657 | 06/10/2023 14:10 |
| 19582 | 4657 | 20/10/2023 16:07 |
| 16595 | 1256 | 22/10/2023 10:49 |
| 18499 | 4635 | 22/10/2023 16:45 |
| 18499 | 4635 | 22/10/2023 21:56 |
| 19610 | 4657 | 23/10/2023 11:57 |
| 19610 | 4657 | 23/10/2023 18:52 |
| 19610 | 4657 | 23/10/2023 18:53 |
| 19610 | 4657 | 24/10/2023 16:08 |
| 18499 | 4635 | 27/10/2023 6:49 |
| 19630 | 4657 | 27/10/2023 10:41 |
| 19630 | 4635 | 27/10/2023 20:33 |
| 19630 | 1538 | 27/10/2023 20:38 |
| 19610 | 4657 | 28/10/2023 11:10 |
| 19610 | 4657 | 29/10/2023 11:00 |
| 18499 | 4635 | 30/10/2023 6:26 |
| 19687 | 4635 | 30/10/2023 11:20 |
| 19610 | 4657 | 03/11/2023 14:48 |
| 19582 | 4657 | 03/11/2023 14:58 |
| 19582 | 4635 | 04/11/2023 15:52 |
| 19582 | 4635 | 04/11/2023 15:58 |
| 18499 | 4635 | 05/11/2023 9:43 |
| 19582 | 4635 | 05/11/2023 17:35 |
| 19882 | 4635 | 06/11/2023 9:39 |
| 19582 | 4635 | 06/11/2023 14:59 |
| 19819 | 4657 | 08/11/2023 16:49 |
| 19819 | 4657 | 08/11/2023 16:58 |
| 19819 | 4635 | 08/11/2023 17:12 |
| 19819 | 1538 | 08/11/2023 19:59 |

Necesito lanzar una consulta con la condición que es que en el mismo día aparezcan los code (4657,1538 y 4635):

El resultado esperado es:

| account_id | code | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19610 | 4657 | 02/10/2023 9:48 |
| 19610 | 4657 | 02/10/2023 19:02 |
| 19610 | 1538 | 02/10/2023 19:43 |
| 19610 | 4635 | 02/10/2023 20:01 |
| 19630 | 4657 | 27/10/2023 10:41 |
| 19630 | 4635 | 27/10/2023 20:33 |
| 19630 | 1538 | 27/10/2023 20:38 |
| 19819 | 4657 | 08/11/2023 16:49 |
| 19819 | 4657 | 08/11/2023 16:58 |
| 19819 | 4635 | 08/11/2023 17:12 |
| 19819 | 1538 | 08/11/2023 19:59 |

Porque cumple con la condición de tener los 3 code (4657,1538 y 4635) y en el mismo día.
He intentado hacer una consulta simple con un `code in(1538,4635,4657)`

```
select * 
from error 
where code in (1538,4635,4657)
```

pero me he atascado con la misma fecha "date".

Comment: gracias por la informacion. He completado.

Comment: Pero vas a indicar en el `WHERE` la fecha también?? Que te trae `select * from error where code in (1538,4635,4657) AND date ='tuFecha' ` ??

Comment: Gracias Ochoa por la informacion, el problema es que necesito ver el resultado de los 3 codes en la misma fecha y no poniendo yo la fecha de la consulta, por eso he atascado, es que no lo se como continuar la consulta, para que me de el resultado esperado.

Comment: @carloslima77 ¿podrías compartir la definición de la tabla `error`? Te la pido porque el formato de fecha que mostras pareciera que `Date` no es un `datetime`

Comment: HeidiSQL es el cliente que utilizás para administrar tu BD. ¿Es MySQL? ¿MariaDB?

Comment: @padaleiana En la primera línea de la pregunta indica, entre paréntesis, que es MySQL

Comment: @DavidJP me limité a ver el título y las etiquetas. Corregido :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vas bien, te falta agrupar por día y asegurarte de que cada día seleccionado tenga al menos esos tres códigos:

```
SELECT * FROM `error`
  WHERE DATE(`Date`) IN (
    SELECT DATE(`Date`)
      FROM `error`
      WHERE `code` IN (1538,4635,4657)
      GROUP BY 1
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `code`)=3
  )
  AND `code` IN (1538,4635,4657);
```

Si los días seleccionados quieres ver otros códigos que no sean estos 3, quita la última condición.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Efectivamente, gracias Marcos. El nombre del campo no tiene por qué coincidir necesariamente con su tipo :) Por los datos que almacena, está claro que es un `DATETIME` aunque lo hayan llamado `Date`

Comment: Lo que quiero señalar es que el formato `datetime` hasta donde yo se almacena valores en el formato `Y-m-d H:i:s`. El OP en su pregunta muestra un formato distinto. Puede ser un error al redactar la pregunta. Tu respuesta es correcta.

Comment: Ah, ¿dices por que le faltan los segundos? Igual es como Heidi los muestra cuando los segundos con :00, ¿o piensas que puede tratarse de un VARCHAR()?

Comment: Ah... puede ser que haya copiado la tabla de Heidi... tiene sentido. Porque, por ejemplo `08/11/2023 19:59` en un campo `datetime` debería ser `2023-11-08 19:59:00`

Comment: Bueno, ya nos dirá. De ser un string, habrá que hacer uso `STR_TO_DATE()` para quedarnos con la fecha

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información. Si perdon el formato Date en realidad es fecha hora es cierto que en la tabla está con en nombre Date pero el formato que sale en Heidi es fecha hora pero realmente para datetime me falta segundos entonces hay que poner STR_TO_DATE() como menciona David JP?

Comment: @carloslima77 No hay que hacer ningún cambio, como es de tipo `DATETIME` está bien así como está. El `STR_TO_DATE()` habría que usarlo si fuera de tipo `CHAR` o `VARCHAR`, y no es el caso.

Comment: @carloslima77, si la respuesta soluciona tu problema, por favor, considera votarla y/o marcarla como aceptada. Mas info en [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)